# Referencing the selected index in a select statment

Tags: vb.net

Rather than using the `Text` property of a `ListBox` I am trying to use the `SelectedIndex` Property such that when I select a certain name in one list box, items are added to another list box. This is the code I am using at the moment.

```
Ward = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
ListBox2.Items.Clear()
Select Case Ward
    Case 
        ListBox2.Items.Add("Fred Jones")
        ListBox2.Items.Add("John Green")
        ListBox2.Items.Add("Imran Shah")
```

If I were using the `Text` property the case would be "Fleming", but what should the case be if I am using the `SelectedIndex` property?

Comment: `Ward = ListBox1.Items(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)`  be sure to test that there IS something selected first.  also: `Ward = ListBox1.SelectedItems(0)` with the same restriction (there must be something selected). `Object Browser` will give you lots of this type of info - **View Menu --> Object Browser** might be F2 on your config.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the `SelectedIndex` is an integer, your case would be something like this:

```
Ward = ListBox1.SelectedIndex
ListBox2.Items.Clear()
Select Case Ward
    Case 1
        ListBox2.Items.Add("Fred Jones")
        ListBox2.Items.Add("John Green")
        ListBox2.Items.Add("Imran Shah")
```

I don't know if that is going to be the best approach though. If your indexes change at a later date, your cases are going to get thrown off. You may want to stick with text.